# Как проверить, совпадает ли пользовательский ввод со словами в .txt файле

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть текстовый файл содержащий:

```
login:admin;password:admin
login:user;password:qwerty
```

Как проверить, совпадёт ли пользовательский ввод с логином и паролем из этого файла? Мой код:

```
name = input("введите ваш логин: ")
a = open("F:\programme\logins.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
b = a.read()
if name in b:
    print("Вы успешно вошли в систему.")
else:
    print("Неверный логин и пароль.")
```

Проблема в том, что можно ввести слова `login` и `password`, проверка будет пройдена и пользователь войдёт в систему.

Это нужно для работы в консоли и не будет использовано где-то на сайте. Прошу по возможности подсказать максимально простое решени - я новичок в python'e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все дело в том, что вы неправильно храните данные в текстовом файле, делать это лучше **словарем**:

```
{0 : {'login' : 'admin', 'password' : 'admin'}, ...}
```

тогда при счете файла вы получите такую конструкцию:

```
x = "{0: {'login' : 'admin', 'password' : 'admin'}, ...}"
```

преобразуем в словарь:

```
x = ast.literal_eval(x)
```

теперь можно спокойно искать наш логин\пароль в логинах\паролях полученного словаря словарей:

```py
for dict in x:
    if input_login and input_password in dict.items():
        print('nice')
        break
```

Comment: Что значит "неправильно"? Хранение просто в текстовом файле с разделением полей определенным символом - один из возможных вариантов хранения данных. Тем более что тут не нужно хранить какую-то сложную иерархическую структуру. Если говорить про неправильность - то неправильно хранить пароль в открытом виде.

Comment: Вот тут у вас с кавычками проблема: `x = '{{'login' : 'admin', 'password' : 'admin'}, ...}'`. И dict из такой строки просто вызвав `x = dict(x)` не получится сделать (тем более что это не словарь, а сет из словарей). Нужно либо `ast.literal_eval()` использовать, или хранить в json вместо dict, и декодировать с помощью `json.loads`.

Comment: @insolor действительно, со словарем ошибся, я естественно имел в виду ast.literal_eval(), сейчас исправлю, а по поводу хранения, это лишние заморочки, если так хочется делить поля - csv в помощь

Answer (score 0):

Просто разбор данных, как они представлены в вопросе

```
def load_logins():
    logins = dict()
    with open('logins.txt') as logins_file:
        for line in logins_file:
            line = line.strip()
            # Проверяем, что строка не пустая
            if line:
                # Сначала разбиваем на части по точке с запятой
                login, password = line.split(';')
                # Потом каждую часть разбиваем по двоеточию и берем правую часть
                # (левую не учитываем, считаем что в строке всегда сначала логин, потом пароль)
                login = login.split(':')[1]
                password = password.split(':')[1]
                # Добавляем пару логин-пароль в словарь
                logins[login] = password

    return logins

login = input("login: ")
password = input("password: ")

logins = load_logins()

if login in logins and logins[login] == password:
    print("Вы успешно вошли в систему.")
else:
    print("Неверный логин или пароль.")
```